# How can I convert this Oracle script to MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to translate this Oracle Scripts to MSSQL:

```
C_LIFECO  CONSTANT CHAR(1)  := '2';
C_FSUCO   CONSTANT CHAR(1 CHAR) := '9';
C_LIFEBR  CONSTANT CHAR(2 CHAR) := '10';
C_USR      CONSTANT CHAR(10 CHAR) := 'MTLBATCH';
C_JOBNM       CONSTANT CHAR(10 CHAR) := 'L2DATAMIGR';
C_INFO      CONSTANT ROW_NUMBER(8) := 2;
C_SECTION_CNT CONSTANT ROW_NUMBER(10) := 500000;
```

This is my attempt but it kept giving me syntax error: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

```
C_LIFECO  CHAR(1)  := '2';
C_FSUCO    CHAR(1) := '9';
C_LIFEBR   CHAR(2) := '10';
C_USR      CHAR(10) := 'MTLBATCH';
C_JOBNM        CHAR(10) := 'L2DATAMIGR';
C_INFO       BigINT(8) := 2;
C_SECTION_CNT  BigINT(10) := 500000;
```

Comment: Please share your syntax error. So one can identify the exact root cause.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, minor syntax will be changed for Declaring the variable.
you should use below one.

```
DECLARE
@C_LIFECO CHAR(1)  = '2'
,@C_FSUCO CHAR(1) = '9'
,@C_LIFEBR CHAR(2) = '10'
,@C_USR CHAR(10) = 'MTLBATCH'
,@C_JOBNM CHAR(10) = 'L2DATAMIGR'
,@C_INFO DECIMAL(8,0) = 2
,@C_SECTION_CNT DECIMAL(10,0) = 500000;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify data size `BigINT(10)/BIGint(8)` in SQL Server just only specify BigINT

```
C_LIFECO  CHAR(1)  := '2';
C_FSUCO    CHAR(1) := '9';
C_LIFEBR   CHAR(2) := '10';
C_USR      CHAR(10) := 'MTLBATCH';
C_JOBNM    CHAR(10) := 'L2DATAMIGR';
C_INFO     BIGINT := 2;
C_SECTION_CNT BIgINT := 500000;
```